# If statement between columns Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, sum, conditional-formatting

Hi I am trying to apply a math formula to column based on a Y/N in a previous column. I would like to apply this to a range of cells in the sheet. EX:

```
If column C = yes

column D = sum(A*B + (0.1*A*B))

else

column D = sum(A*B)
```

Again, i would like to apply this to a whole sheet. Also, column C is a drop down list Yes or no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try in D2:

```
=INDEX(IF(C2:C="yes"; (A2:A*B2:B)+(0.1*A2:A*B2:B); A2:A*B2:B))
```